# Application Insights not logging with Azure Functions C#. Namespace seems the problem

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, microsoft-extensions-logging

Our function delegates all the logic to another class "CreateHandler" where we use the ILogger through DI. The function logs properly but the CreateHandler does not. Locally we verified that it does not log to the console, UNLESS we change the class namespace to something that starts with "Function". That means that FunctionR or FunctionS will work but RFunction or SFunction won't. We are dealing with that class and a service. Clearly our service has a completely different namespace and we would need to keep that one, while logging at the same time. How can we make the class log without changing the namespace?

CreateHandler class (logging right):

```
using ExampleProject.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionAnything
{
    public class CreateHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CreateHandler> _logger;

        public CreateHandler(
            ILogger<CreateHandler> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Handle(Car car)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"This is logging properly");
        }
    }
}
```

CreateHandler class (not logging):

```
using ExampleProject.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExampleProject.Functions.Handlers
{
    public class CreateHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CreateHandler> _logger;

        public CreateHandler(
            ILogger<CreateHandler> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Handle(Car car)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"This is not logging");
        }
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
using ExampleProject.Functions.Handlers;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(ExampleProject.Functions.Startup))]
namespace ExampleProject.Functions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<CreateHandler>();
        }
    }
}
```

Function:

```
using ExampleProject.Domain.Entities;
using ExampleProject.Functions.Handlers;
using ExampleProject.Service.Constants;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ExampleProject.Functions
{
    public class Function
    {
        private readonly CreateHandler _createHandler;

        public Function(
            CreateHandler createHandler)
        {
            _createHandler = createHandler;
        }
        
        [FunctionName("Create")]
        public async Task Create([QueueTrigger(QueueNames.Create)] Car car)
        {
            log.LogInformation("I'm logged");
            await _createHandler.Handle(car);
        }
    }
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code where the logging happens and how the ILogger is injected?

Comment: @NoahStahl done ✔

Comment: Looks good comparing with mine. On the application insights blade of your functions app in the portal, do you see "Application Insights is linked through Instrumentation Key in app settings"?

Comment: We have the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY setting with a value. But as far as I understand, that is only for the deployed function. I'm first trying to make it work locally.

Comment: @NoahStahl More testing reveals something more weird, it logs if the namespace starts with Function, that means that it will work with FunctionSomething, but won't with UFunction

Comment: Weird, I can say I have the same type of setup with a DI-injected service class that handles function logic from a different namespace. Is it the case that you can reproduce this by starting with a vanilla function from template and it breaks only when namespace is changed?

Comment: Yes, I did and it breaks. Does your service by any chance start with the word Function?Like FunctionSomething? If so, change that to anything else and see if it logs. I tried with a new template and didn't work either.

Comment: Neither my namespace or class have "Function" prefix. Maybe worth raising an issue in the app insights or functions SDK github repos....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed this issue in github before(if the namespace is not started with Function), but currently cannot find it.

The solution is that, you should add the completed `namespace+class` name in `host.json` if the namespace is not started with Function. Like below:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "ExampleProject.Functions.Handlers.CreateHandler": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Or a general way:

```
"logLevel": { "Default": "Information" }
```

Comment: Thanks, it does solve the problem indeed. I've also accomplished it in a more general way by setting     "logLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }

Comment: Great! I included it in the answer:)

Comment: My limited testing shows that you don't need the fully qualified namespace too, so you could just use "ExampleProject.Functions" if you wanted to catch everything logged from that namespace